# How to handle json response using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

i am new in nodejs (using expressjs) and i am calling a rest api,i am getting 
response as json in console(with two keys "id" and "text") but now i want to get "text" from
json response and want to pass in "assistant.ask",How can i do this ?

Here is my code

```
function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         console.log(body);  //working
         assistant.ask(body.text);  // not working            
        }
    else{
        console.log(error); 
        }
```

Comment: can you include the code of your HTTP request?

Comment: @BorysKupar: Here is http request code

var request = require('request');
let rawInput = function (assistant) {
    let rawInput = assistant.getRawInput();
    request.post(
    'http://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/api/v1/240/respond',
    { json: { query: rawInput } },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your response is array, you need to access first item:

```
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
         assistant.ask(body[0].text);     
    }
    else {
        console.log(error); 
    }
}
```

Comment: in console,i am getting following response

[ { recipient_id: '240',
    text: 'If you\'re bored, you could plan your dream vacation.' } ]

Comment: okay, looks like your response is already a JSON. But it's an array, and you need to access first item of it: `assistant.ask(body[0].text);`